# Using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end with a nested repeater

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use ng-repeat to go through a nested tree-like array.

#### [Plunkr Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5z95S1?p=preview)

***HTML***

```
<div layout></div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="layout">
  <div class="layout" ng-repeat-start="data in data.nodes" ng-include="data.name"></div>
  <div ng-repeat-end>End of repeater</div>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="box">
  <div class="box">Box</box>
</script>
```

***JavaScript***

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.directive('layout', function() {

  return {
    templateUrl: 'layout',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.data = {
        'nodes': [
          {
          'name': 'layout',
          'nodes': [{'name': 'box'}, {'name': 'box'}, {'name': 'box'}, {'name': 'box'}]
          }, 
          {
          'name': 'layout',
          'nodes': [{'name': 'box'}, {'name': 'box'}, {'name': 'box'}, {'name': 'box'}]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

My problem is that I need a way to figure out when I'm in the last item of a particular level in the array, but since Angular follows recursion by going deep-first, I can't use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`:

[image: Problem]

The expected result, of course, is:

[image: Expected outcome]

How can I know whether I am at the end of a particular level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `$last` to determine when you're at the end of each iteration:

```
<div ng-show="$last" ng-repeat-end>End of repeater</div>
```

This is giving me the latter result in your question.